# Как вывести title на странице категории товаров с ListView Django?

Tags: django, listview

Вывожу товары на страницах категорий с помощью ListView. Все отлично выводится и фильтруется, но не могу вывести title, description и другие поля из модели Category. Вот модель товара:

```html
class Item(models.Model):
"""Товар"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category',related_name="items", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

А это модель категории:

```html
class Category(models.Model):
    """Категории"""
    title = models.CharField("Категория", max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True)
```

Views:

```html
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
"""Товар"""
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
    
    
class CategoryView(ListView):
    """Категория товаров"""
    model = Item
    queryset = Item.objects.order_by('?')
    paginate_by = 24
    template_name = "category.html"
```

На странице Category.html вывожу название категории так:

```html
<h1>{{ self.title }}</h1>
```

В результате не выводится ничего (список товаров и пагинация выводится нормально). 
Подскажите, как можно сделать вывод названия текущей категории, сохранив вывод списка товаров?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне нет объекта `self`

Можешь получить категорию так

```
{{ object_list.0.category.title }}
```